# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure when trying to refresh data set in Power BI

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssl, powerbi

I have connected Power BI with Postgres and published the report to Power BI App i.e. ***https://app.powerbi.com/*** everything is working fine my report is getting generated.

But when I apply ***Shedule Refresh*** on my data set I am getting below error.

`An error happened while reading data from the provider: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. Table: public Machine.`

Can anyone please help me with this. I am new to Power BI by looking at the error it seems something with SSL Certificate but I don't have much idea about it.

My Postgres DB is on Azure.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. :(